# Quoting surrounds its output with pipes - why?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have created a table `daily-planet` as follows:

```
(setf daily-planet '((olsen jimmy 123-76-4535 cub-reporter)
                     (kent  clark 089-52-6787 reporter)
                     (lane  lois  951-26-1438 reporter)
                     (white perry 355-16-7439 editor)))
```

Now I want to extract the social security numbers by running `mapcar` as follows:

```
(mapcar #'caddr daily-planet)
```

The result is:

```
(|123-76-4535| |089-52-6787| |951-26-1438| |355-16-7439|)
```

I would have expected:

```
(123-76-4535 089-52-6787 951-26-1438 355-16-7439)
```

When I tried to run the more simple

```
'(123-456)
```

I have seen that it also was evaluated to:

```
(|123-456|)
```

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has nothing to do with evaluation.

```
CL-USER 84 > '123-456-789
|123-456-789|

CL-USER 85 > (type-of '123-456-789)
SYMBOL
```

`123-456-789` is a symbol. The printer might print it as `|123-456-789|.` The reason: it has only digits and the `-` character in its name, which makes the printed representation a so-called *potential number*.

The pipe character is an escape character for symbols. It surrounds the symbol string and that will be the symbol name.

```
CL-USER 86 > '|This is a strange symbol with digits, spaces and other characters --- !!!|
|This is a strange symbol with digits, spaces and other characters --- !!!|

CL-USER 87 > (symbol-name *)
"This is a strange symbol with digits, spaces and other characters --- !!!"
```

For some reason the printer may think that `123-456-789` should be printed escaped. But the symbol name is the same:

```
CL-USER 88 > (eq '123-456 '|123-456|)
T
```

Escaping allows symbols to have arbitrary names.

A useless example:

```
CL-USER 89 > (defun |Gravitation nach Einstein| (|Masse in kg|) (list |Masse in kg|))
|Gravitation nach Einstein|

CL-USER 90 > (|Gravitation nach Einstein| 10)
(10)
```

The Backslash is the single escape (by default characters will be upcased):

```
CL-USER 93 > 'foo\foo\ bar
|FOOfOO BAR|
```

*Side note*:

Common Lisp has the idea of *potential numbers*. There is a number syntax for various number types: integer, float, ratio, complex, ... But there is room for extension defined by the standard. For example 123-456-789 might be in an extended Common Lisp a number! When the printer sees a symbol which looks like it could be a potential number, it escapes the symbol, so that it can safely read back as a symbol...